# How to check if Object and its properties exist?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I receive an object from an API call. I want to check:

1. If the object exists
2. Whether the object's property has the property I'm looking for or not

Let's say that I'm expecting the following object of objects:

```
success.response.data.users.items.list
```

Now I want to know if this `list` object exists or not.

I have tried:

- `typeof success.response.data.users.items.list !== "undefined"`

  Error I got: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`
- `success.hasOwnProperty("response.data.users.items.list")`

  This always evaluates to false because `hasOwnProperty` cannot check multi-level objects apparently.
- `success.response.data.users.items.hasOwnProperty("list")`

  Error I got: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Is there any modern and quick way of checking this?

Comment: lodash.get https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

Comment: why use lodash when there are language features available?

Comment: The root of your problem is that `success` does not have a property called `response`. As Will Jenkins said in his answer, you need to check all the previous levels of the chain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's an option for you, [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is the way to go:

```
success?.response?.data?.users?.items?.list || {}
```

if not, you just have to check that each object exists before attempting to access a child property, or use ES6 destructuring with defaults (pretty gnarly with deeply-nested objects though):

```
const { response: { data: { users: { items: { list = {} } = {} } = {} } = {} } = {} } = success || {}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, but my list is an object as well. Optional chaining isn't really an option for me, unfortunately.

Comment: If it's an object it doesn't really change the solution... Have updated though

Answer (score 2):

If optional chaining is not an option, you could use something within those lines:

```
success && success.response && success.response.data && 
success.response.data.users && success.response.data.users.items && success.response.data.users.items.list
```